# Fatal error: Class 'Mustache_Engine' not found

Tags: php, windows, ubuntu-12.04, mustache

I'm using Mustache for my project and I'm following the documentation for it .. which is ..

```
define('DS', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);
require 'system'.DS.'mustache'.DS.'Autoloader.php';
Mustache_Autoloader::register();
$m = new Mustache_Engine;
```

Mustache sits in `system/mustache` folder. The funny thing is, it works just fine under Windows. But on my server (ubuntu 12.04) it says `Fatal error: Class 'Mustache_Engine' not found`. My PHP is the same as my Windows's, so I really don't understand what could be the issue here. All help is appreciated.

Comment: Are you able to show the auto loader code?  If it works on one server, but not another, it might have something to do with the php setting "include_path"

Comment: It's right here: https://github.com/bobthecow/mustache.php/blob/master/src/Mustache/Autoloader.php

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `mustache` folder containing `Autoloader.php` needs to be capitalized, to match the capitalization of the class names. Welcome to case-sensitive filesystems :)

In general, you should treat the project root as either the repository itself, or the `src` folder inside the repository. All subdirectories are there to make the project and autoloader [PSR-0 compliant](https://github.com/php-fig/fig-standards/blob/master/accepted/PSR-0.md).

So put the Mustache.php repo itself in `/system`, giving you `/system/mustache/src/Mustache/Autoloader.php`.

Answer (score 1):

I had similar problem, but path was correct. 
I was missing `Mustache_Autoloader::register();`
It took me a while to spot it